# 3d tool for visualising programming concepts

Tags: 3d, visualization

Could anyone direct me to any applications that let you visualise object oriented code as if the code was represented by 3d objects with corresponding elements for inputs and sequence within a call/execution path? I saw 'code bubbles' a while ago as a way to structure fragments of code but can't find an appropriate search term for this kind of tool if it exists.